# how to add 2 value of a column with respect of a group and an indicator

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose

```
  Household     person     loop     utility      indicator
      1           1          1        3             1    
      1           1          1        4             0    
      1           1          1        5             0    
      1           1          1        6             1 
      1           1          2        3             0    
      1           1          2        3             0       
      1           2          1        2             1    
      1           2          1        7             1    
      1           2          1        8             1 
      2           1          1        3             0    
      2           1          1        3             0
```

in each household and each person, if indicator is 1 , I want to add the value of utility for first and last row of each loop . (if the indicator is 1 for first row of loop it is 1 for last row as well). Also it does not matter what is indicator for middle rows of loop

first person in first family:  the indicator is 1 in first and last row of loop so I will add 3+6 , indicator is 0 for his second loop so I don't need it you can put it in out put as NA 
output

```
  Household     person     loop     utility      
      1           1          1        3 +6                                               
      1           2          1        2 +8
```

Answer (score 0):

We can `filter` groups where `first` and `last` `indicator` value is 1 and `sum` `first` and `last` `utility` value for them.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(Household, person, loop) %>%
  filter(first(indicator) == 1 & last(indicator) == 1) %>%
  summarise(utility = first(utility) + last(utility))

#  Household person  loop utility
#      <int>  <int> <int>   <int>
#1         1      1     1       9
#2         1      2     1      10
```

---

In base R, it is bit lengthy

```
aggregate(utility~Household+person+loop, subset(df1, 
     ave(indicator == 1, Household, person, loop, 
          FUN = function(x) x[1L] & x[length(x)])), 
          function(x) x[1L] + x[length(x)])
```